# Attach triangles to div

Tags: css

Since all questions I've found are about the "comment box arrows";

I'd like to make a DIV which looks like this

[image]

I need to attach two triangles to a div container, but I'm not sure how to do this. Currently my code looks like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yJEyOm

```
.expand {
  width: 200px;
}

.expand:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
}

.expand:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 0;
  border-color: transparent #007bff transparent transparent;
}
```

The problem here is that the triangles are not shown in total, just a part of it. How to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OXEPmB ?
The problem is the position of the pseudo-elements.

```
.expand {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #007bff;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.expand:after {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  border-color: #fff #fff #fff #007bff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.expand:before {
  content: " ";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: #fff #007bff #fff #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  background:red;
  height:20px;
}
div:before{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,0);
  border-top: 23px solid red;
  border-left: 16px solid transparent;
  border-right: 16px solid transparent;
  height: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
span{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,0);
  bottom:-20px;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Expand</span>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```css
.container{
   width: auto;
  background-color: #007bff;
  height:20px;
}

.expand {
  position:absolute;
  width: 85px; 
  height: 0px; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  border-top: 20px solid #007bff;
  margin-top:18px;
  margin-left:25px;
 
}

.expand p{
  margin-top:-20px;
  padding-left:12px
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>
    <div class="expand"><p>expand</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This allows you tot add and customize whatever you want. Just add img and customize spaces and done.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <style>
   a { text-decoration:none; }
   ul, ul li { margin:0; padding:0; }
   ul li { display:inline-block; }
   ul li a { background: url('navrepeater.png') repeat-x #efefef; line-height: 20px; display:inline-block; }
   ul li a:before, ul li a:after { 
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }
   ul li a:before { background: url('left.png') no-repeat #ccc; }
   ul li a:after { background: url('right.png') no-repeat #ccc; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
  </ul>

 </body>
</html>
```